# Rails Throws RecordNotDestroyed Exception on destroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a batch worker that goes through and updates the database by cleaning up a table and then repopulating it. Specific rows in the database should be prevented from being destroyed and so I have a `before_destroy :dont_destroy_record` callback to make sure I don't delete specific records.

The problem I am having is that active record throws an exception when calling `collection.destroy_all`, `ActiveRecord:RecordNotDestroyed`. This is thrown whenever the `:dont_destroy_record` callback returns false for those specific records.

A couple solutions to the problem is wrapping `collection.destroy_all` in a try-catch or I could loop through the collection calling `destroy` on each object. Are there any other possible, or better, solutions to this problem? One constraint is that I can't change this batch worker very much since it is used in quite a few other projects and needs to be super generic.

It seems odd to me that `destroy_all` would throw that exception since it is calling `destroy`. I'm also not seeing much in the documentation regarding throwing the exception.

Comment: Instead of trying to decide if you should destroy something in a `before_destroy` callback, could you instead filter the initial collection to the ones that you DO want to destroy, and only destroy those?

Comment: No, because filtering the collection would require me to change the batch worker and that wouldn't work

Comment: You will need to loop over the collection then, since that's all destroy_all is doing. Just unroll it; you can even call the callback manually in the loop, like, records.each { |record| next if record.dont_destroy_record; record.destroy }  or you can just use rescue in the loop (some people think rescue is slow or lazy or bad programming, that's their opinion, man.)

Comment: If you use `destroy` instead of `destroy!` it should not raise the error, so you don't even need to catch it - just leave a comment in that loop for future-you so you know it may not actually destroy it :)

Comment: Well put Court3nay.  Most people would frown on building a rescue clause for an "expected" error.  How big is your data set of records?

Comment: @court3nay - I know `destroy` shouldn't throw an exception but it still is. It may be because of cascading destroys, idk, but it's annoying

Comment: @bkunzi01 - Data set could be around 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some good comments to this question, and I thought I'd put together a full answer that includes the gist of some of those comments, as well as code examples and upside/downside analysis for each approach.

## Rescue

With this, you unroll the `destroy_all` to `destroy` each record individually.  This will allow you to detect when the exception is thrown on each record, and simply ignore the exception and continue on:

```
collection.each do |record|
  begin
    record.destroy
  rescue e => ActiveRecord:RecordNotDestroyed
    puts "Record #{record.id} not destroyed"
  end
end
```

The downsides:

- some may find this unenlightened Ruby, or just bad practice

The upsides:

- it certainly works
- it passes the [GSD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GSD&defid=3491422) test

## Filter records with validation function before destroy

If your validation function `dont_destroy_record` is accessible to you, you could pre-test the collection and only destroy those records that pass muster.

```
safe_to_destroy = collection.select {|record| !record.dont_destroy_record }
safe_to_destroy.destroy_all
```

The downsides:

- your code has to have access to the `dont_destroy_record` function
- `dont_destroy_record` should not have side effects
- this doubles the number of calls to `dont_destroy_record` for the records in `safe_to_destroy`, so there could be a performance implication
- there could be a race condition if the results of `dont_destroy_record` could change (user activity, background processes, etc) between the first and second calls for a given record

The upsides:

- You only call `destroy_all` on records that are safe to be destroyed, given the criteria above

## Improve query to only return destroyable records

This requires access to the query that returns the `collection` to be destroyed.  This query would include the same conditions checked for in the validation function.

Let's assume that this is a task at *Soulless Corp*, and they're getting ready to Selectively Separate (fire") the highly compensated employees that have at least 30 days on the job as part of their monthly purge process.  The original query might look like this:

```
collection = Person.joins(:employees).where(salary_level: :highly_compensated).where("person.hire_date < ?", DateTime.now - 30)
```

Also assume that the validation checks ensure that the Person object isn't a boss or doesn't have staff assigned.  Maybe the condition looks something like this:

```
return false if role == boss && employees.any?
```

We can roll that into a single query, imagining it something like this:

```
collection = Person.joins(:employees).where(salary_level: :highly_compensated).where("person.hire_date < ?", DateTime.now - 60).not(role: :boss).group(employee_id).having("COUNT(employees.id) = 0")
```

Using this approach with our imaginary models would give us a filtered collection that we could then *safely* use `destroy_all` on.  And then everyone's happy except the employees that were involuntarily participated in *Soulless Corp*'s monthly Vocational Relocation Program.

The downsides:

- requires re-thinking and testing the query
- requires access to change the query
- requires keeping the query logic in sync with the validation logic

The upsides:

- may reduce database query overhead significantly
- calls to destroy_all don't need explicit error handling/avoidance mechanisms
- You don't work for *Soulless Corp*

Comment: good summary! minor bug, i'd replace  `dont_destroy_record(record).nil?` with `!!record.dont_destroy_record` - both because the method is on the record, and false.nil? == false :)

Comment: "some may find this unenlightened Ruby, or just bad practice" -> BECAUSE you are rescuing an exception you intend to see thrown; whereas rescue should be something unexpected, by its classical definition. :)